# Replacing values in numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have a very large list of lists containing numpy ndarrays where I need to map letters to an integer value.

This is along the lines of what I was thinking might work, but it doesn't seem to catch all arrays.

```
import numpy as np

x = [np.array(['a','b','c']),np.array(['d','e']),np.array(['a','e'])]
dict_x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e':5}

x[ x == 'a'] = dict_x.get('a')

Output: [1, array(['d', 'e'], 
  dtype='<U1'), array(['a', 'e'], 
  dtype='<U1')]
```

I was also trying to iterate through all of the keys to replace them in the array one by one with the following

```
for i in dict_x.keys():
    x[ x == i] = dict_x.get(i)
```

but this returns, which I suppose makes sense. Anyone have any clever ways to replace all of these values at once and in all instances? Thanks very much!

```
[5, array(['d', 'e'], 
  dtype='<U1'), array(['a', 'e'], 
  dtype='<U1')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
x = [np.array(['a','b','c'], dtype="<U4"),np.array(['d','e'], dtype="<U4"),np.array(['a','e'], dtype="<U4")]
dict_x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e':5}

for i in x:
    i[ i == 'a'] = dict_x.get('a')

x = array(['1', 'b', 'c'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['d', 'e'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['1', 'e'],
      dtype='<U1')]
```

Comment: Yes - exactly. I just made a loop to loop through all of the keys in the dictionary as an outer loop and then put yours as the inner loop with a variable for where 'a' was. I was hoping for a one shot replace all, but I think should still be O(n), so no harm I guess, right? Thanks!

Comment: I just found out this truncates the number to a single digit. So, 1000 is read in as 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Because the dtype of array is '<U1', if you define `x = [np.array(['a','b','c'], dtype="<U4"), np.array(['d','e']),np.array(['a','e'])]`, then it works as you expected.